# Wrong library links on SE Android app's "About" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

While checking the links on the About page, I noticed this:

**Butterknife** returns a 404-error (with any browser)

The two links to github.com (Android-PullToRefresh and Crouton) run into a timeout when used with OrWeb:

[image: using OrWeb]

With Chrome it is ok.

Comment: The correct link to Butter Knife should be http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife.  Regarding OrWeb, I think it's offtopic since I'm not sure SE can fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OSS attributions will be updated and corrected in 1.0.84. OrWeb's problems are out of our hands.